# Bluetooth Speaker disconnects after some time

Tags: bluetooth, speakers, disconnect

I am using a JBL Flip 4 Bluetooth Speaker in Ubuntu 16.04. After connecting the speaker, the speaker automatically disconnects after sometime. To reuse the speaker, I have to turn my Bluetooth Off then ON. The time gap between disconnection of speaker is not constant and varies from 5 minutes to 1 hour. My speaker works fine with my phone, Ipad and Windows, therefore I am sure there is no issue with the speaker. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?